# Get users AD details when logged into Outlook Web Addin

Tags: azure-active-directory, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

Im still battleing with trying to pull down the details of the logged in (Outlook) user within the add in im developing.

I have exploered the EWS service but, as far as I cant tell, the functions I need are not available so I have started looking at the Outlook REST API.

I can get very basic user details with the following call:

```
    function sendFindPersonRequest() {

    //get auth token for Graph
        Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true }, function (result) {
        if (result.status === "succeeded") {
            var accessToken = result.value;
            console.log('REST Access Token : ' + accessToken);
            // Use the access token.
            getCurrentItem(accessToken);
        } else {
            // Handle the error.
        }
    });}

    function getCurrentItem(accessToken) {

    // Construct the REST URL to the current item.
    // Details for formatting the URL can be found at
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations#get-messages.
    var getMessageUrl = Office.context.mailbox.restUrl +
        '/v2.0/me/';

    $.ajax({
        url: getMessageUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken }
    }).done(function (item) {
        // Message is passed in `item`.
        var subject = item.displayName;
        console.log('item subject: ' + subject);

  }).fail(function (error) {
    // Handle error.
});
}
```

But this doesnt pass any more than Alias, DisplayName and Emailaddress.

```
@odata.context: "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Me"
@odata.id: "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/Users('')"
Alias: "Joe.Bloggs"
DisplayName: ""
EmailAddress: "Joe.Bloggs@emailhere.co.uk"
Id: "baf52ae4-............"
MailboxGuid: "257f3fe1-6.............."
```

Im looking to get extendeddetails such as Jobtitle, OfficeAddress etc (which are standard AD fields).

I have looked at the GetUser method as well but that returns the same. I really dont want to go down Graph route and it feels that I am missing something as really expect those other fields to be there.

Has any one else used this to better affect?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see where we can create extensions for a user based on [Office 365 Data Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/extensions-rest-operations#supported-rest-resources) and [Outlook Extended Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/extended-properties-rest-operations#supported-rest-resources).

And [Microsoft.OutlookServices.User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#user) also doesn't have such properties as Jobtitle, OfficeAddress etc.

When I tried to use the OData `$select` query parameter like:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me?$select=DisplayName,Jobtitle,OfficeAddress
```

It will give an error: `"Could not find a property named 'Jobtitle' on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.User'."`

I'm afraid that what you want is not available in Outlook REST API. You should use Microsoft Graph API or AAD Graph API instead.

---

**Update:**

We can use `GET https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/people?$search=""` to find the person's information.

Comment: I thought as much, i had the same outcome when trying to use a query parameter but wondered if it was just down to me not knowing the correct names/terms.

Comment: @SimonBloodworth All properties of a user has been listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#user. Check if there are any similar ones you are looking for.

Comment: So looking at https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata that looks to have a Person object with all the properties required, but dont see a way of accessing.

Comment: @SimonBloodworth It's the properties of Contact: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#contact. It's not the property of Me, but my contacts. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/contacts-rest-operations#GetContacts

Comment: @SimonBloodworth Sorry I have made a mistake. The Person object indeed exists. But the document seems not to mention it. You can access it using `GET https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/people`. But it retrieve a collection of person objects ordered by their relevance to the user, which is determined by the user's communication and collaboration patterns, and business relationships. It's not the property of the user neither. You can find the similar endpoint in Microsoft Graph: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-people?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.

Comment: thank you - Office.context.mailbox.restUrl + '/v2.0/me/people?$search="simon.bloodworth@emailhere.co.uk"'; gave me access the majority of all the data i need, for some reason it doesnt return OfficeLocation, BusinessAddress etc though which is annoying as need that too!  many thanks for your help though!

Comment: @SimonBloodworth BusinessAddress is not a property of People while OfficeLocation is. OfficeLocation should be able to got. Make sure you update it in the right place. Now that it's what you need, I'll update my answer to include it.